# Android - App running even without required intent.action

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

EDIT: Actually, it is solved in the comments, I was just curious how it could work but as I see there's nothing special about it. Thanks to Simon

I was looking for the answer quite long but found nothing, every question was about something NOT working, but this one is about how the hell it can work? 
I made a little app which uses SDK 8 (Android 2.2) , and it is able to receive sms when it comes immediately and write it to a text file. Interesting thing is, it is working after reboot, which I believe it shouldn't because it does not have this line in manifest

> action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"

Why is that?

Main

```
public class Main extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    read();
}

public void read()
{
    Cursor c;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");

    c = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
            new String[] {"address", "date", "body" }, 
            null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(c);

    while (c.moveToNext())
    {

        //write to file
        }       
        c.close();
         writeToExternalStorage();
}


private void writeToFile(String data) {

}

    private void writeToExternalStorage() {


    }

private String getDate(long time) {

}
 }
```

Receiver

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,  Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs=null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle!=null)
    {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i = 0;i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.smslogger"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smslogger.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Because you've registered a `Receiver`?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html  Congratulations.  Your app is working as designed.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that too and I learned that it is able to work even when in background but I thought I have to startup the app when the phone is started but I don't. So is it enough to register Receiver? I don't need to "start" the app after boot anymore?

Comment: Ok thanks so now why is this needed in some apps? action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" . Is it for service instead of a receiver? I am happy that my app works I was just curious

Comment: Nope.  Read the docs, once you register a Receiver, it will receive matching broadcast intents regardless of whether your app is running or not.  It's how SMS apps, email clients etc can receive events without having to run at boot or as services.  BOOT_COMPLETED is another intent that does exactly that - calls apps that register for  boot complete events.

Comment: Thanks one more time. Yeah Well after some confusing reading in docs before, I started to prefer looking for stackoverflow questions rather than reading docs from android website.  But could you clarify this? - I register a receiver. It will match intents even without launching the app at startup. So android has some lets say "table of receivers" which is searched after intent is sent and then application is invoked or I got it completely wrong? :-D

Comment: Correct.  Android stores a list of registered receivers which it dispatches intents to.